# Getting relational data with pointer in Parse

Tags: parse-platform

We are facing a problem reading data from relational tables. We have table1 ,which has in one of its columns a pointer to another table , called table2 . We need to get the data in table2 , from table1's pointer in one query request .

So, the query right now is :

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"table1"];
[query whereKey:@"completed"  equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
[query whereKey:@"userId" equalTo:[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"Users" objectId:@"someID"]];

[query  findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error)
     {

         //new user
         if(objects.count==0)
         {

         }

         else
         {
           //here we get "Users:vAJS2T96V1" ,which is the pointer to table2 ,but we need to go deeper to the other table 
           // in the same query, and get the data from table2 .
         }
     }

 }];
```

How do we get the data from table2, in one query ?

Comment: How are you doing on this? Have you gotten any further?

Answer (score 3):

You use "includeKey" to fetch the data from the other table:

```
[query includeKey:@"Users"];
```

More info: http://blog.parse.com/2011/12/06/queries-for-relational-data/

Comment: I believe that this is incorrect. `includeKey` only works for `Pointers` not `Relations` despite the usage of the term "relational" in various places in that post. As mentioned in another post on this page, this clears it up: https://parse.com/questions/pointer-vs-relation

Comment: @JaredH The OP is about pointers: "We have table1 ,which has in one of its columns a pointer to another table , called table2 ." There is no mention anywhere of "Relations"

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this problem (in JS) at have not been able to fix it yet. Since the replication of this problem is very straightforward, I suppose that Parse.com lacks this functionality as of right now. There is an [official answer](https://parse.com/questions/pointer-vs-relation) ([2](https://www.parse.com/questions/include-relation-one-to-many-javascript)) (taken from "parse questions archive") to the discussed problem that confirms my assumption.

Kevin Lacker (Parse staff)

> In general "include" only works well for pointers. Relations might
>   have far more objects being related to than can be included in a
>   response.

Jamie Karraker (Parse staff)

> Yes that is the limitation when you use relations.